# JS Plotly odd margin top

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using `PlotlyJS` to make my charts. However my horizontal bar chart has some odd padding / margin on the top:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

**CODE**

```
    angular.module('Chart').directive('advancedChart', function (seriesGenerator) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div> </div>',
        scope: {
            chartData: '=',
            valueKey: '@',
            labelKey: '@',
            orientation: '@',
            seriesType: '@',
            shapes: '=',
            customSeries: '=',
            seriesKey: '@',
            labelFilter: '@',
            labelGroup: '@',
            callback: '=',
            customSize: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var plotElement = element[0];
            var myPlot = document.getElementById('uniqueId');
            var layout = {};

            if (scope.customSize) {
                var height = scope.chartData.length * 50;
                layout = {
                    height: height
                }
            }

            if (!scope.orientation) {
                scope.orientation = 'v';
            }

            if (!scope.seriesKey) {
                scope.seriesKey = scope.labelKey;
            }

            seriesGenerator.generateAdvancedPlotlySeries(scope.chartData, scope.labelKey, scope.valueKey, scope.seriesType, scope.orientation, scope.seriesKey, scope.labelFilter, scope.labelGroup)
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (scope.shapes) {
                        layout.shapes = scope.shapes;
                    }
                    layout.margin = {
                        l:250,
                    };
                    layout.showlegend = false;

                    if (scope.customSeries) {
                        result = result.concat(scope.customSeries);
                    }

                    createChart(result);
                });

            function createChart(charData) {
                Plotly.newPlot(plotElement, charData, layout);

                plotElement.on('plotly_click', function (data) {
                    if (scope.callback != null) {
                        var returnData = {
                            y: data.points[0].y,
                            x: data.points[0].x
                        };
                        scope.callback(returnData);
                    }
                    console.log('y: ' + data.points[0].y + ' ' + 'x:' + data.points[0].x);
                });
            }

            window.onresize = function () {
                var update = {
                    width: element.parent().width();
                };
                Plotly.relayout(plotElement, update);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Impossible to help you without any code, don't you agree?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado il add code to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with angular but I think you should set the margin-top value to 0.
As you can see in the reference (https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-margin) the default value of layout.margin.t is 80. So change your code to that:

```
layout.margin = {
    l:250,
    t:0
};
```

btw: maybe now the modebar-buttons on top of each plotly graph aren't visible anymore. For that you could try `t:30` or other values.
Hope it helps:-)